# Mustache doesn't Evaluate {{}} inside function

Tags: mustache, momentjs

I am trying to format JS Date () object with moment.js with mustache, however mustache doesn't pass evaluated value to function.

In backbone view:

```
render: function () {
    var user = this.user.toJSON ();  //model

    _.extend (user, {formatLastLoginAt: this.formatLastLoginAt});

    var rendered = mustache.render (template, user);
    this.$el.html (rendered);

    return this;
},

formatLastLoginAt: function () {
   return function (lastLoginAt) {
     return moment (lastLoginAt).format ('Do MMMM YYYY');
  }
}
```

user object binding:
[image: user object before pass to mustache]

In template:

```
{{#lastLoginAt}}
    <tr>
     <td>Last Login:</td> 
     <td>{{#formatLastLoginAt}}{{lastLoginAt}}{{/formatLastLoginAt}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/lastLoginAt}}
```

`moment.js` gives `NaN` error as 'lastLoginAt' pass in as literal string "{{lastLoginAt}}" rather than its `Date ()` value.

Tried with `moment ().format ()`, it works. Thus the lambda construct should be ok and `{{#lastLoginAt}}` is non-empty.

Anything I missed out?  Appreciate your advice.  Thank you.

Comment: Lambdas aren't given raw values. They can give you the rendering of the inner section, though, that you may parse in order to rebuild the original value... Not practical at all, but that's the best you can do with this tool. Some other Mustache implementations, in other languages, are more convenient, and empower the lambda construct (for instance, https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/rendering_objects.md)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mustache won't render the contents for you. Your function takes one argument, `lastLoginAt`, but Mustache will pass you another: `render`. Calling `render` with `lastLoginAt` will expand the variable:

```
formatLastLoginAt: function () {
   return function (lastLoginAt, render) {
     lastLoginAt = render(lastLoginAt);  // expand variable
     return moment (lastLoginAt).format ('Do MMMM YYYY');
  }
}
```