# Handling inner tags in Mustache's TemplateFunction

Tags: scala, mustache, handlebars.js

I have a scala method in a controller that handles `{{_tl2}}{{/tl2}}` tags.

```
 def tl2 = {
    new TemplateFunction() {
      override def apply(input: String): String = {
        util.getLength("tag_2", input)
      }
    }
  }
```

It works fine when the mustache contains statements such as  `{{_tl2}}Hi, hello{{/i}}`

However, when I have tags such as `{{_tl2}}{{my_sentence}}{{/tl2}}`, it passes "{{my_sentence}}" as is, without expanding it. So I understand I need to expand `{{my_sentence}}` in the TemplateFunction.apply method. Is there a way I can accept some sort of function in apply that I can use on "input"?

Edit: I found a similar question and solution for mustache.js, but none for its java implementation.
[Mustache doesn't Evaluate {{}} inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120261/mustache-doesnt-evaluate-inside-function)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to directly use Guava's `new com.google.common.base.Function[String, String]()` instead of `TemplateFunction`.

Here's the updated definition

```
import com.google.common.base.{Function => GFunction}

def tl2 = {
    new GFunction[String, String]() {
      override def apply(input: String): String = {
        util.getLength("tag_2", input)
      }
    }
 }
```

Credit: Got the answer offline from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491266/sam-pullara